# AngularJS - filter a ng-repeat list by an other ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

From this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/pkxPa/), I'm trying to filter an ng-repeat list by some button generated by an other ng-repeat list.

I have two lists that share the same property:

- $scope.products => product.category_id
- $scope.categories => category.id

I generate these lists in my html with ng-repeat and I want to be able to filter the products list using the category button also generated with ng-repeat.

### Controller

```
$scope.categories = [
    {name: 'Category 1', id: 1}, 
    {name: 'Category 2', id: 2}, 
    {name: 'Category 3', id: 3}, 
];

$scope.products = [
    {name: 'Product 1', category_id: 1}, 
    {name: 'Product 2', category_id: 2}, 
    {name: 'Product 3', category_id: 2}, 
    {name: 'Product 4', category_id: 3}, 
    {name: 'Product 5', category_id: 3}, 
    {name: 'Product 6', category_id: 3}
];
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller='ctrl'>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='category in categories'>
            <input type="button" value='{{ category.name }}'
               ng-click='showcat = {category_id: {{ category.id }} }' />
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='product in products | filter:showcat'>{{ product.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CJLG/1/)

But it's not working :( I tried to create a custom filter in my controller but I get the same result.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [
        {name: 'Category 1', id: 1}, 
        {name: 'Category 2', id: 2}, 
        {name: 'Category 3', id: 3}, 
    ];

    $scope.products = [
        {name: 'Product 1', category_id: 1}, 
        {name: 'Product 2', category_id: 2}, 
        {name: 'Product 3', category_id: 2}, 
        {name: 'Product 4', category_id: 3}, 
        {name: 'Product 5', category_id: 3}, 
        {name: 'Product 6', category_id: 3}
    ];
    $scope.showcat = { };
    $scope.setShowCat = function(id){
                $scope.showcat = {category_id: id };


    }
}
```

And html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='category in categories'>
                <input type="button" ng-click='setShowCat (category.id)' value='{{ category.name }}' />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='product in products | filter:showcat'>{{ product.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ng-repeat` creates its own child scope, so when you set `showcat` inside the `ng-repeat` like you're doing, it's only local to that scope. Create a `$scope` function:

```
$scope.setShowcat = function(id) {
    $scope.showcat = {category_id : id};
}
```

And then call:

```
<input type="button" value='{{ category.name }}' ng-click='setShowcat(category.id)' />
```